# Informal way of asking something

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Care for a quick call?

Can I use this phrase to ask my friend for a quick call to discuss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this would be informal but appropriate (since you are talking to your friend). You also give them the option to say no if they are busy/don't want to.

An alternative you can use:

> Do you mind giving me a quick call/me giving you a quick call?

Comment: Any other alternatives that I could use in the similar situation

Comment: @santhosha You could use *Do you mind giving me a quick call/me giving you a quick call?*